# I have edited /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections but the IP settings remain the same

Tags: centos, networkmanager

I am running CentOS stream 9, when looking in directory /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections I see one file ("enp0s1.nmconnection"), I made copy the file in the same directory named "enp0s1.nmconnection.old". After editing the original file, and restarting NetworkManager through systemctl, my IP settings stay the same. How do I force NetworkManager to use the settings defined in the /system-connections directory?

Comment: try moving the `.old` file out of that folder - I'm not sure NetworkManager cares what file extensions you use, so it may well be reading both files, and since `.old` file is "alphabetically" later, I suspect its settings are being used instead of the settings in the original file you edited